# Optimising python code that uses numpy sin,cos,sum and abs

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have some python code that currently runs too slowly for it to be useful. Having done some speed tests, the bulk of the time seems to be spent performing mathematical operations to calculate corr (see code below).

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing

def calc_cc(tlag):
    global phi_t, psi_t, T
    tstart = tlag-T/2
    x = np.arange(tstart, tstart+T, dtype=int)

    #bulk of time spent running line below calculating corr
    corr = np.sum(np.abs(np.cos(phi_t[tlag+x]-psi_t[x]))-np.abs(np.sin(phi_t[tlag+x]-psi_t[x])))


def main():
    global phi_t, psi_t, T

    phi_t = #some large numpy array
    psi_t = #another numpy array
    tlag = #another numpy array

    with closing(Pool(processes=5)) as p:
        corr = p.map(calc_cc,tlag)
        p.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have spent some time looking around online to find ways to optimise my python code, and more specifically mathematical operations, but a lot of the advise stems around using packages such as numpy instead of python base functions where required (for example using np.sum vastly increases the speed when compared to sum(). Having now got to a point where I am using numpy arrays, with numpy methods, I am not sure where else I can find additional gains. The formula I am effectively trying to solve is:

[image]

I am sure there must be a better way of doing this, so any guidance towards a better solution would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: What's `time_lag'?  Assuming that's typo, I'd calculate  `phi_t[tlag+x]-psi_t[x]` just once. For a single value `math.cos` is faster, but for a large array (many `x` values) `np.cos` will be faster.

Comment: yup that is a typo, fixed. Regarding the array size (x), generally len(x) > 10000.

Comment: Regarding calculating phi_t[tlag+x]-psi_t[x] just once, how can this be done when it varies depending on tlag, which is being passed each function call.

edit: oh I see what you mean now. you are referring to within the cosine and sine functions. This improved the speed by 20%, which is a nice start! :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can improve your code slightly by computing `phi_t(...)-psi_t(...)` once for both trigonometric functions [as @hpaulj noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748288/optimising-python-code-that-uses-numpy-sin-cos-sum-and-abs#comment74540674_43748288). However, the biggest issue I see is that you're using a multiprocessing pool for a comparatively light calculation. My guess would be that large part of your runtime comes from overhead by using the pool.

In case you can fit in memory, you can compute your whole correlation function by making use of array broadcasting. By vectorizing your calculation, you'll maximize the speed-up you can get via numpy. The idea is to use 2d arrays indexing your `phi`/`psi` arrays: columns correspond to the original `x` indices, and rows correspond to individual `tlag` shifts. The built-in numpy functions you're using naturally make use of broadcasting.

Here's what I mean, complete with some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np

def calc_cc_new(tlags):
    global phi_t, psi_t, T

    tstarts = tlags - T//2
    xs = tstarts + np.arange(T)[:,None]
    dphipsi = phi_t[tlags+xs] - psi_t[xs]

    corr = np.sum(np.abs(np.cos(dphipsi)) - np.abs(np.sin(dphipsi)),axis=0)
    return corr

def main_new():
    global phi_t, psi_t, tlags

    return calc_cc_new(tlags)

N = 10000
T = 100
phi_t = np.random.rand(N)*2*np.pi
psi_t = np.random.rand(N)*2*np.pi
tlags = np.arange(T//2,3*T)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main_new())
```

I didn't check your multiprocessing version, but the serial version of your original took 8.1 ms while the vectorized version took 2.1 ms (whether or not I separated the two terms of the summation into separate calls to `np.sum()`). I checked that the returned array from my version checks out with the original using `np.allclose` (due to vectorization the order of arithmetic operations is moved around, so we can't expect *exact* agreement, only one within machine precision). With the dummy example it didn't matter whether I defined the summation dimension to be the zeroth or the first, but depending on your input array shapes this might lead to some performance differences.

Furthermore, use of globals are usually discouraged, and global namespace lookup is marginally slower than a local one (though I don't expect this to matter in case your function is CPU-heavy). Anyway, if you ditch the multiprocessing pool, you can simply extend the definition of your `calc_cc` function so that it gets all its inputs as parameters, rather than globals.

Finally, don't forget that `1/N` prefactor once you're finished.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback! :) some useful tips. Regarding the vectorization of the problem, I tested the method and found that it speeds up the process when T is small, though for large values of T the original version ran faster. Is this a known / expected case?

Comment: edit: by T is small, I mean len(tlags) is small, and vice versa for a large value of T (following from tlags = np.arange(T//2, 3*T) in your example)

Comment: @nat1707828 I guess it could be expected, actually. The vectorized code is 4 times faster in my dummy example than the serial one, but you're using 5 processes to do the work. So in case your runtimes have similar ratios, and the setup/teardown of the multiprocessing pool becomes negligible, then you can be faster with the latter approach. Could you tell me a typical size of your arrays so that I can try playing around with dimensions?

Comment: in the previous case, I was using a dummy example without the additional processes also, so essentially reflecting your own example. The reason for using multiple processes in my main code is I found it greatly improved the speed. The size of tlags is approximately 25000, the value of T is 90000, and the sizes of phi_t and psi_t are also approximately 90000

Comment: @nat1707828 bad news: the 25000x90000 array of doubles that we need for the vectorized version would be above 16 GB raw data alone...that can also imply that the vectorized version runs out of memory which induces [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)), thereby horrendously increasing runtime. I'll try to think of something by chopping up the calculation to chunks. In the mean time, it's a bit weird that you have T=90000 and ~90000-long data, since `x` are integer indices of length `T`, and you're even shifting that. I might be missing something obvious though.

Comment: makes sense, I can see that with vectorization my script very quickly gets up to 50 GB of memory. Might be okay on high-speed servers, as opposed to my local machine, but would likely draw some complaints from other people running scripts! On array sizes, phi_t and psi_t are the calculated instantaneous phase of a signal with length T. The values for tlags go from -12500 to 12500, so there aren't any issues with the indexes (if this is what you are referring to?)

Comment: @nat1707828 that was exactly my point: `x` indices start at `tlag - T/2`, so in this case most of these values are negative, which are measured from the end of the array. Or is there an exact periodic boundary condition which makes this work?

Comment: yeah i noticed this also, and thought it unusual, but have been able to reproduce results when compared to an original FORTRAN script solving the same problem (my intention was to rewrite it into python). So for the mean time, I have used this as a first order validation of the scripts method.

Comment: @nat1707828 OK, then I won't worry about that. But note that fortran allows negative indices if the arrays are defined such, whereas in python negative indices wrap back to the end of the list/array. It wasn't clear whether you knew this already, so better to be safe than sorry:)